# SSRS custom sort with calculated column in a matrix

Tags: sorting, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix in SSRS report as shown below where Month_end is the column group and I have added columns - Q1 Total,Q2,Q3,Q4 with expression where Q1 Total=Sum of values for Jan, Feb and Mar and so on for others. Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 and Total 2021 are not query fields, they are calculated using expressions SUM and IIF.

[image]

Below is the expected output. I want the columns in this order.  How do I sort them this way. If I sort the columns by the Month_end date, they will come in order - Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May etc. but I want to get Q1 Total column after Mar and Q2 column after Jun and so on.  I have tried doing custom order but didn't know how to reference Q1 Total column in the sort order as it is not a query field.  How do I sort them as shown in the expected output.

[image]

Comment: I believe you can add another parent COLUMN Group by Quarter with a column for the Q Total to make it work like you want. I'm not able to test it right now tho.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If I add another column group by Quarter, on which column do I need to sort by to get the way I want?

Comment: As Alan has mentioned, the sort by Quarter on the Quarter Group and then sort the months group by month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need (if you don't already have) some form of ID for the month, quarter and year against each record.

So "May 2021" would be Month 5, Quarter 2, Year 2021.

- In your column groups, start with the months, order this group by month
- Next, add a parent group to the month group that groups by quarter, order this group by quarter
- Finally add a parent group to the quarter group that groups by year,
  order this by year.

The expressions for all the value columns (month, Quarter and Year totals) will all b ethe same. They can then be simple sums e.g.

```
=SUM(Fields!Sales_Value.Value)
```

There is no need to have IIF statements in you expression if the data is grouped correctly.